# Centered table with links that span a two column article

Tags: css, html-table

I've been trying to get a table to span a two-column article container using `column-span:all` in my CSS-file. The spanning part works, but my problem is that I've got a couple of links inside my table that for some reason don't work in Chrome (v 85) and Ms Edge. By not working, I mean that I cannot click the links and while hovering over them, no change takes effect (`a:hover` does nothing). The issue doesn't seem to appear using Firefox or IE.

If I remove `margin: 2em auto;` the links work again, but then my table isn't centered.

So, the question is, how can I make a centered table that spans a two-column article container with still functioning links across Chrome, IE, FF, Safari (not tested) etc?

Is there perhaps an alternative?

MWE:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      article{column-count:2;}
      a{color:green;}
      a:visited{color:red;}
      a:hover{color:blue;}
      a:active{color:yellow;}
      table{column-span:all;margin:2em auto;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a></td>
          <td>unimportant text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="https://www.duckduckgo.com/">duckduckgo</a></td>
          <td>another unimportant text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      article{column-count:2;}
      a{color:green;}
      a:visited{color:red;}
      a:hover{color:blue;}
      a:active{color:yellow;}
      .center{
         column-span:all;
         margin:2em 0;
         display:flex;
         justify-content:center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article>
     <div class="center">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a></td>
          <td>unimportant text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="https://www.duckduckgo.com/">duckduckgo</a></td>
          <td>another unimportant text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```